# Equation of a terrain

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

I am looking for a method to create an infinitely differentiable equation $f(x,y)$ describes a surface that meets the following criteria:
$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$0\leq f(x,y)$
Given a discrete set of points $S$, $z=f(x,y)$ has a local minimum in every one of these points and only at these points.

So far I have tried simplifying the problem by setting all the points the same $z$ coordinate and keeping them in a "grid" structure. Functions in the form of $f(x,y)=\sin(ax)+\sin(by)+2$ seem to work nicely with infinite "grids" but I haven't been able to improve on that.

Comment: I think that, if you want this to work, you might need $S$ to be discrete.

Comment: If $S$ is finite, try $z=\Pi_i ((x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2)$. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=local+minima+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%28%28x%2B2%29%5E2%2B%28y-3%29%5E2%29)